# Hex offsets, can someone help?

Tags: hex

I'm confused about offsets.
If someone tells me to edit something at the offset "0x0805F4B0",
what would I type in my hex editor's "Jump To" function?

Answer (score 3):

I would hope the editor would make clear what form of input it expects there.  Ideally, `0x0805F4B0` would work.  Failing that, I would try `0805F4B0` and `805F4B0`.  As a last resort, I'd try `134608048` (i.e. `0x0805F4B0`<sub>10</sub>).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... which question such answer... may be you must enter 0805F4B0 in 'jump to'? Or you can enter this number converted to decimal value? Any modern calculator can convert numbers between hex and dec